# Teradata function to format number not working

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I have this in my select statement:

```
CAST(AVG(
CASE
  WHEN nps.nps_score < 7 THEN -1
  WHEN nps.nps_score > 8 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END 
)*100 AS FORMAT 'ZZ9%') AS NPS
```

The problem is, the format isn't applied, the column return is:

```
-28.571428571428573
-66.66666666666667
-75
```

Managed to get the format I want (for example: 28.6%) as follows, but it doesn't seem so efficient.

```
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(AVG(
CASE
  WHEN nps.nps_score < 7 THEN -1
  WHEN nps.nps_score > 8 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END 
)*100,'99V.9'),'%') AS NPS
```

Do you know why the FORMAT function doesn't work?

Comment: It's working for me, I think there must be something missing.

Comment: A `FORMAT` clause only applies when the *database* is doing the conversion to/from character string. (e.g. when applying CAST as VARCHAR, or TO_CHAR) - not when the client is doing the conversion.

Comment: Hrm, to clarify this works for me in SQL Assistant. In both BTEQ and TD Studio, it returns an integer (no decimals).

Comment: Something like `CAST(CAST(numeric_expr AS FORMAT ... ) AS VARCHAR(n))` should "work" everywhere because it forces the database to apply the FORMAT. Or use TO_CHAR (though the V shown immediately preceding the decimal is redundant)